# How to do sorting and then numbering on an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

As an example I have a database with the following information

```
Name      Number

Boris

Trevor

Arthur

bessie

big Dave

BOB
```

I want to be able to sort that data in the below order and then add a number to the number column in that specific order

```
Name      Number

Arthur    1

BOB       2

Boris     3

big Dave  4

bessie    5

Trevor    6
```

I can select using the order I have specified using

```
select DB.TABLE.NAME  , case
           when row_number() over(partition by lower(DB.TABLE.NAME ) 
                  order by DB.TABLE.NAME ) = 1
                   then 1
                   else 0
                 end as result
           from DB.TABLE;
```

but I then have no idea how to apply the numbers to the numbers column.
If I try a different method of sorting, I can use a sequence to apply the numbers but the order is not what I want. It seems to be the row_number() function that is causing me problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have written in the SQL is...  The first occurrence of each name should get 1, and all other occurrences should get 0.  Is that what you intend?  Because it doesn't match the example you gave.  Is your issue writing this as an UPDATE, or that you don't get the values you require?

Comment: @Jamsplodge Where would the name "BORAT" come? Before "BOB", between "BOB" and "Boris", or after "Boris"?

Comment: @Jamsplodge Also, what's the logic of your order?

Comment: Unfortunately the logic of my order is an old proprietary system that sorts in this way that I need to replicate. I don't actually care about the column in the select query containing the 1s and 0s. That is an unintended consequence of the sorting of the name column being in the order I want.

Comment: BORAT would come after BOB and before Boris... I think o_O

Comment: @Jamsplodge I would encourage not _not_ to store values in the data that rely on values in other rows.  As soon as you add or update a row you're going to have to reorder the entire set and change the order number.  Just add an appropriate index and do the ordering on-the-fly.

Comment: @Jamsplodge What is the actual logic for the ordering? Why does "BORAT" come after "BOB", but "big Dave" comes before "bessie"?

Comment: It shouldn't - I made a mistake. Imagine "bessie" actually says "big dave". Sorry, my brain hurts as usual.

Comment: So, is the order: Capital letters have priority over lower case letters? B comes before b, etc? Also, please update your question to ensure that the expected output is in the desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into the_table t
using (
    select rowid as rid,
           row_number() over(order by lower(name)) as result
   from the_table
) nr on (nr.rid = t.rowid)
when matched then update 
  set "number" = nr.result;
```

I am not sure what the `CASE` should do. It only returns 1 or 0 but the expected result shows you want numbers from 1 to 6, so I removed the `CASE`

If you have a proper primary key on the table, it's better to use that instead of `rowid`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
with sample_data as (select 'Boris' name from dual union all
                     select 'Trevor' name from dual union all
                     select 'BO Derek' name from dual union all
                     select 'Arthur' name from dual union all
                     select 'big dave' name from dual union all
                     select 'big Dave' name from dual union all
                     select 'BOB' name from dual union all
                     select 'BORAT' name from dual union all
                     select 'Brian' name from dual union all
                     select 'Big Bad Dom' name from dual)
-- end of creating a subquery "sample_data" to mimic a table with data in it.
-- see SQL below:
select name,
       row_number() over (order by upper(substr(name, 1, 1)),
                                   name) row_num
from   sample_data
order by upper(substr(name, 1, 1)),
         name;


NAME           ROW_NUM
----------- ----------
Arthur               1
BO Derek             2
BOB                  3
BORAT                4
Big Bad Dom          5
Boris                6
Brian                7
big Dave             8
big dave             9
Trevor              10
```

To update a table, you'd do something like (assuming name is a unique column):

```
merge into some_table tgt
using (select name,
              row_number() over (order by upper(substr(name, 1, 1)),
                                          name) row_num
       from   some_table) src
  on (tgt.name = src.name)
when matched then
update set tgt.number = src.row_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   select DB.TABLE.NAME  , 
           row_number() over(ORDER by DB.TABLE.NAME ) as Number
      from DB.TABLE
    order by DB.TABLE.NAME;
```

Maybe you are looking to update db.table in that case:

```
update DB.TABLE
    set number = (select row_number() over(ORDER by DB.TABLE.NAME ) as Number
                  from DB.TABLE t1 where t1.name = DB.TABLE.NAME );
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for your suggestions.

I went with this hacky approach to the answer by @a_horse_with_no_name

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NEWSEQ
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1;

merge into DB.TABLE t
using (
    select rowid as rid, DB.TABLE.NAME, case
           when row_number() over(partition by lower(DB.TABLE.NAME ) 
                  order by DB.TABLE.NAME ) = 1
                   then 1
                   else 0
                 end as result
           from DB.TABLE
) nr on (nr.rid = t.rowid)
when matched then update 
  set NUMBER = NEWSEQ.NEXTVAL;

drop sequence NEWSEQ;
```

It may not be the most efficient way to do it, but it works

Comment: I don't think that this approach of using a sequence like that is reliable. You're probably getting lucky if it seems to be working. You would be better off using @a_horse_with_no_name's actual answer, except for the fact that the `partition by` clause should be removed, I think.

Comment: The `row_number()` function should have simply been: `row_number() over (order by lower(db.table.name)) as result`, without the `case` expression.

Comment: But the partition by bit is the clever bit! Using the answer that @a_horse_with_no_name gives sorts them properly but then doesn't update the number column properly. The sequence does exactly what I need. I've tried it on all of the tables that need sorting like this and it works, so I'm gonna keep it as it is.

Comment: Order by lower doesn't do the sorting exactly as I wanted. It's close but not quite right.

Comment: *But the partition by bit is the clever bit*... huh? I'm not sure you understand how it works. Anyways, I can't force you to do anything. But to me, it's pretty clear that simply fixing the `row_number()` function call to be *less clever* would work perfectly. Your approach is asking for trouble.

Comment: I really don't understand how it works :) I just know that if I go with the row_number() over (order by lower(db.table.name)) as result approach that it's not in the correct order when I'm done

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean the approach is wrong. It only means that you haven't described your desired ordering clearly. There is no doubt that the correct numbering expression should simply be: `row_number() over (order by <some-expression>) as result`. Now, what `<some-expression>` actually is, that's up to you. But that's the only part you should have to worry about.